# creating entity with datastore-entity returns null

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the [datastore-entity](https://github.com/komlasapaty/datastore-entity) package in an application to interface with Google Cloud Datastore.

I am able to create entities fine but I was hoping to get the entity's key/ID once it is saved like you can when doing `datastore.Client.put(entity)` using google's library. Instead I just get a null object.

```
import sys
import datetime
from datastore_entity import DatastoreEntity, EntityValue

class UserModel(DatastoreEntity):

    username = EntityValue()
    password = EntityValue()
    # active = EntityValue(1)
    date_created = EntityValue(datetime.datetime.utcnow())

    __kind__ = "user"
    __exclude_from_index__ = ['password']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UserModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def make_user(cls,username):
        user = cls()
        user.username=username
        user.save(id=username)
        print(f"making user: {user.key}", file=sys.stderr)
        return user


hilly = UserModel.make_user("hiliarybilliary5005")
print(f"the key for hiliarybilliary is: {hilly.key.id_or_name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue in the datastore-entity library.  The code does not set self.key in the `save()` method.  Please file an issue on github.